# ExtJs replacable items

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to create something like this

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        id: 'cmpWithReplacebleItems'
    });

    Ext.getCmp('cmpWithReplacebleItems').items = [new SomeComponent()];
});
```

code of SomeComponent

```
SomeComponent = Ext.extend(Ext.Viewport, {
   layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'test',
            title: 'My Panel'
        }]
 });
```

As you can see i want 'cmpWithReplacebleItems' items to be replaceble. But when i try this code i get some errors while resizing...

**The question is.. what is the right way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a component is constructed, you can't modify the items directly like that.  You want to use the `Ext.Container` methods `add`, `remove`, or `removeAll` to modify the items.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        id: 'cmpWithReplacebleItems'
    });

    var cmp = Ext.getCmp('cmpWithReplacebleItems');
    cmp.add(new SomeComponent());
    cmp.doLayout(); //important to layout again after adding/removing
});
```

Comment: tnx, i actually find this by my self a minute ago :D but really tnx for you answer..